# htaccess, detect urls without dot, dash, slash, spaces or underscore

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

We need to create a rule on htaccess that will redirect a page according to the url. if the path or last part of the url has only letters or numbers, no underscores, dots, slashes or dashes, we want to use that string found and send it as a parameter to another php page that will decide how to use it.

Something like this:

suppose that `/^([^\.,\-,\_,\/]+)` means all except `'.', '-', '_', '/' and spaces`

```
RewriteRule /^([^\.,\-,\_,\/]+)$ handler.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

where $1 will give us a string with letters and numbers only.

For example:

```
mysite.com/someone = handler.php?alias=someone
```

and

```
mysite.com/styles.css   or   mysite.com/images/logo.jpg   or   mysite.com/page_2, etc
```

will not be redirected.

I am really lost with regular expressions. Any Ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: The `^` means start of subject. But you are expecting an `/` even before that; which won't work. Also if you are looking for just letters and numbers, then use `\w` instead of a negated charclass.

Comment: `\w` does not include whitespace, while his expression does.

Comment: Also spaces should not be taken into consideration! Good point @JohannesH. Thanks, I will update the question.

Comment: That was more or less rethorical - whitespace should never be present in URLs.

Comment: Can someone explain the negative vote, I want to improve the way I formulate my questions in future, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ handler.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ handler.php?alias=$1 [NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9]+$ handler.php?alias=$0 [NC.L]
```

Comment: Same issue as the original: you're matching from the beginning (`^`) to the end (`$`) and there must not be a non-word character - which is not the case. It's just the part after the last `/` that should be matched.

Comment: @JohannesH. - You are not right, as for `site.com/url` RewriteRule will carry only `url` on the left side of the command.

Comment: Yupp, 'cause the domain isn't part of the path that is used. Using `site.com/test/me` however your expression won't match anything, but it SHOULD match the `me`.

Comment: @JohannesH. - Read question again... It says `mysite.com/styles.css   or   mysite.com/images/logo.jpg   or mysite.com/page_2, etc will not be redirected.`. Got it?

Comment: So? That's no info about files that are inside subdirectories. But there is no need to argue here. This answer still exists, so wheover reads it can decide himself. Jeez, we'Re not in Kindergarden anymore.

Comment: Just for fun, what would be the answer using negations as I was originally trying to do? Thanks :)

Comment: I think we can write a regexp like ^([^\x00-\x2f\x3a-\x40\x5b-\x60\x7b-\xff]+)$

Answer (score -1):

try

```
RewriteRule ^.*([^\/\.\-_]+)$ handler.php?alias=$1
```

[Edit]: If you don't want to match whitespace (that should never be present in URLs, so that shopuldn't even make a difference, but still ^^), do

```
RewriteRule ^.*(\w+)$ handler.php?alias=$1
```

Comment: Of course, that is why I dont want spaces! :D thanks, I will try it